# Optimize MySQL query with many subselects

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

I have to maintain an application with SQL commands (article management).

One query looks like this:

```
SET @from_timestamp = '2013-07-01 00:00:00';
SET @serialnumber = '%aaaa01%';

SELECT
    test1.article,
    test1.serialnumber,
    test2.`timestamp` as test2_timestamp,
    test2.additionalinfo,
    test1.`timestamp` AS test1_timestamp,
    test1.text0 AS test1_text0,
    test1.text1 AS test1_text1,
    test1.text2 AS test1_text2,
    test1.text3 AS test1_text,
    test3.text1 as test3_text1,
    test3.`timestamp` AS test3_timestamp,
    test3.`status`,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, test1.`timestamp`, test3.`timestamp`) as DeltaT
FROM (
    SELECT
        max(`timestamp`) AS TIMESTAMP,
        article,
        serialnumber,
        text1,
        text2,
        text3,
        text4
    FROM exampleTable
    WHERE
        test = 'test1' AND
        `timestamp` >= @from_timestamp AND
        os0 LIKE @serialnumber
    GROUP BY serialnumber
) AS test1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        max(`timestamp`) AS TIMESTAMP,
        serialnumber,
        status,
        text1
    FROM exampleTable
    WHERE
        test = 'test3' AND
        `timestamp` >= @from_timestamp
    GROUP BY serialnumber
) AS test3 
ON test1.serialnumber = test3.serialnumber
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        max(`timestamp`) AS TIMESTAMP,
        serialnumber,
        article,
        text1
    FROM exampleTable
    WHERE
        LENGTH(serialnumber) = 13 AND
        test = 'test2' AND
        `status` = -1 AND
        `timestamp` >= @from_timestamp
    GROUP BY serialnumber
) AS test2 
ON test1.serialnumber = test2.serialnumber
ORDER BY test1.`timestamp`
```

It is working with only one table where product data is saved. But as expected, this query is really slow. Is there any optimization possible?

Edit: [Attached image of the explain sql result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2pXi.png)

Edit2: The table has many data (last COUNT(*) provides 39589279 ;-) )

Edit3: [Attached image of the explain table result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzLkZ.png)

Edit4: Please don't blame me for table definition, it is very old developed by other guys and it is not possible to change it without breaking changes.

Comment: Which columns have index?

Comment: Can you show us an `EXPLAIN` result?

Comment: There are following indices: id (primary key), article, test, serialnumber, timestamp

Comment: If you want us to help optimize a query, **you need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly.  If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well.

Comment: Also, I would *strongly* recommend against using `timestamp` as a column name.  You're just asking for trouble, starting with all the extra quoting you have to do.  Rename it `stamp` and live life happy.

Comment: Added explain result. For the column names: Yes I know that but it is not possible to alter the table (old application used in production) - also added count of rows.

Comment: Updated both EXPLAIN pictures.

Comment: In the second subquery you group by sno. Shouldn't this also be serialnumber ?

Comment: yes you're right.. in the original table it's called sno, but for clarification I changed the names for the question. - fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you qre querying three times the same table and join afterwards. The first simplification would be to use only one select :

```
SELECT
    article,
    serialnumber,
    text1,
    text2,
    text3,
    text4,
    max(case when 
        test = 'test1' AND
        os0 LIKE @serialnumber
    then `timestamp` else null end) AS test1_timestamp,
    max(case when 
        LENGTH(serialnumber) = 13 AND
        test = 'test2' AND
        `status` = -1
    then `timestamp` else null end) AS test2_timestamp,
    max(case when 
        test = 'test3'
    then `timestamp` else null end) AS test3_timestamp,
FROM exampleTable
WHERE
    test in ('test1', 'test2', 'test3') AND
    `timestamp` >= @from_timestamp
GROUP BY serialnumber
```

This will already give you a great improvement.

Secondly, you have to put an index on the `timestamp` column to improve speed.

Comment: That looks good, but I want to display text1-4 values from the row with test = test1 and additional text1 from another row with the same value in serialnumber field with test = test3. Is this just another `case when`?

Comment: Yes, you could ti do like this. But since you group on `serialnumer`, you must also use a group function on these rows, and put the `case when` inside.

Comment: I tested your query without modifications (just field names) and it was VERY slow compared to the statement in the question (duration 27.391 sec / fetch 55.468 sec, while the original query takes: duration 21.812 sec / fetch 0.156 sec).

Comment: Did you create the index ? Without the index on `timestamp` it won't work well.

Comment: No, as I mentioned in my fourth question edit, it is not possible (or to be clear: not allowed for me) to change anything on the database. Then I will keep the original query, but thank you for your help.

Comment: An additional index does no harm at all. Your boss can't allow you this ? Or is he afraid ?

Comment: It is one instance of a world wide deployed system in our company. Doing changes mean a big internal process. But I can see the benefits of that index.